# The titlepage option and the table of contents in KOMA-Script

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, titles, koma-script

The KOMA-Script document classes provide the `titlepage` option which when set to `true` typesets the title at its own page and otherwise allows for content to immediately follow the title on the same page. For the `scrreprt` class the default is `titlepage=true` and I want to set it to `false` but I get an unexpected result if `\maketitle` is immediately followed by `\tableofcontents`, i.e. there is a page break before the table of contents. (If `\maketitle` is followed by a section, then there is no page break.)

On the other hand, the default for `scrartcl` is `titlepage=false` and in that case the table of contents immediately follows the title so I'm pretty sure that there is an easy way to achieve this for `srcreprt` too, but I can't find it.

Here's a small code sample.

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false]{scrreprt}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section*{intro}
\chapter{A}
\section{a}
\section{b}
\section{c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do understand the logic behind these designs, but they don't necessarily agree with what I want. In particular, `scrartcl` is not what I want. I want to produce a document divided into chapters (each starting on a new page) and a concise table of contents that would fit very nicely just below the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage=false]{scrreprt}

\setuptoc{toc}{leveldown}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section*{intro}
\chapter{A}
\section{a}
\section{b}
\section{c}

\end{document}
```

[image: titlepage]

Comment: Thanks! At first I was somewhat confused by the explanation of `leveldown` in the manual, but it is indeed what I need.