# specify the exact page for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

If am  using documentclass like book,  is it possible to force the table of contents to appear on a particular page say page 17?

Comment: If you have control over the location, then sure. I guess rather than changing the page number to be 17 on the first page of the ToC, you're interested in filling 16 pages prior to the ToC with stuff, and then insert the ToC. Could you provide more substance to the usage of your request?

Comment: What would be the contents of pages 1 to 16? Or would you just want to set the pagenumber to 17? You can you the `\cleardoublepage*` and `\clearpage*` commands to insert blank pages if you want to. If this is not what you're after please provide more details.

Comment: For example can I control the TOC to appear on the title page (which is on page 1.)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136000/1952)

Comment: why not `\setcounter{page}{17}` just before `\tableofcontents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using for example [afterpage](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage).

Update replaces generation of chapters with `\loop` with the use of `blindtext` package. And it adds a `\clearpage` after `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\def\TimeForToc?{\ifnum\value{page}<17 \afterpage{\TimeForToc?}\else
                  \tableofcontents\clearpage\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{\afterpage{\TimeForToc?}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The pages `17-18-19` (partially cropped from the `dvipng` conversion):

[image: page 17]
[image: page 18]
[image: page 19]

Comment: @karlkoeller thanks for caring `;-)`

Comment: @user21778 you're welcome. The space after `17` is not optional: in case you need to change the page to something else either keep a space after the new page number or put a `\relax` after it (the `\relax` is less susceptible to disappear if you edit again the code later).

Comment: do you use `\maketitle`? what is *exactly* your document class?